# 403 status code when posting form with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I have a form in my template file like this

```
 <form action="#"  id="details" class="inline">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% for field in practice_form %}
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                     {{field.label_tag}}
                     {{field}}
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <input type="submit" id="save-practice" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Details">
         </div>  
     </div>
 </form>
```

My js

```
 $("#save-practice").on('click', function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/settings/add-practice-data/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR){
            if (! data['success']){
                form.trigger('reset');
                alert("Something went wrong, Please try saving practice again.");
            }

        }
    });    
});
```

and the django view

```
def add_practice_details(request):
    practice = PracticeData.objects.all()
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        if practice:
            form = PracticeDataForm(request.POST, instance=practice[0])
        else:
            form = PracticeDataForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            practice_data = form.save()
            data = dict(success=True)
        else:
            data = dict(success=False)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

The view checks to see if there is data allready saved so it edits them or creates new one. But I get a 403 error. I do have csrf_token imported in my template html file. What can be wrong?

Comment: it's not related to csrf. Seems like request.is_ajax() return False.

Comment: How did you guess that? It looks like it won't even execute the view

Comment: It's a [common issue](https://www.google.nl/search?q=django+is_ajax+jquery&oq=django+is_ajax+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i64.15639j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: But i have many ajax calls and all work great with similar code...How come it is not working now?

Comment: I guess that, because you manually raise 403 Error if it is not POST request or request.is_ajax()

Comment: In every case i raise PermissionDenied. In chrome console if I run $.get('add-practice-data'), it raises PermissionDenied but request.is_ajax() is true, as it's suppose to

Comment: It was my fault...I added some div's and had changed the parent...
now i had to do $(this).parent().parent().parent()...Is there an easier way to get the form or is it accepted?

Comment: You can use: $(this).parents('form:first)

Comment: @Apostolos how did you come over this issue ?